# VBA Code for Multi Drop Down Auto-Filters in Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below example Range Table in a Workbook

[image: Worksheet Gif]

With the following VBA Code within Worksheet named "Drop Down"

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$B$2" Then
    If Range("B2") = "All" Then
        Range("A5").AutoFilter
    Else
        Range("A5").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("B2")
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

[image: Worksheet Module]

which works well auto-filtering Column B on changing selection in Dropdown List in B2.

However, I am wanting to put Multiple Filters from Dropdown Lists in C2 and C3 that will auto-filter for example column C and/or column D on changing selection s from their relevant Dropdown lists of those columns.

I have tried various iterations and also see am unable to insert more than the ONE Worksheet Module. I have also tried with 'Else' and inserting further lines within the code, to no avail.

Please could a learned colleague help and avise me, that I may apply the code to one of my work projects.

Many thanks

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The logic of multiple drop-down is similar as your code.
- ***Note:*** If you require dynamically loading dropdown lists, additional code is necessary. For instance, selecting "AA" from the first dropdown would then filter the options in the second and third dropdowns to only display items with "AA" as their item name.

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.CountLarge property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.countlarge?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144247)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Range.CurrentRegion property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144111)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Application.Intersect method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:D2")) Is Nothing Then
        With Me.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
            If Target.Value = "All" Then
                If Me.AutoFilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column
                End If
            Else
                .AutoFilter Field:=Target.Column, Criteria1:=Target.Value
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Update:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const HEADER = 4
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:D2")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim vCol, vCrit
        vCol = Application.Match(Target.Offset(-1), Me.Rows(HEADER), 0)
        If VBA.IsError(vCol) Then Exit Sub
        With Me.Range("A4").CurrentRegion
            If Target.Value = "All" Then
                If Me.AutoFilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol
                End If
            Else
                vCrit = Target.Text
                If IsDate(vCrit) Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=CLng(CDate(vCol)), Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlAnd
                Else
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @taller appreciated, first class, exactly what I was looking for.
A couple clarification questions if I may, I take it the drop-down list cells need be in the same column as the columns data that you want to filter?
For some reason, when applying a drop-down list to my date column as above, and I select a date, nothing is filtered, even though all other filters are All?

Comment: Likewise with the Commission column in my example, even though have ensured the formats are the same both in the dropdown list and the column of data?

Comment: I've uploaded a demo to answer your questions.

Comment: Thank you @taller , perfect, appreciated for your trouble.

Comment: Hi@taller, please could I get some more help?
I have tested with variation with following code changes `Const HEADER = 7` , `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B5"))` (Vertical instead of Horizontal), `vCol = Application.Match(Target.Offset(0, -1), Me.Rows(HEADER), 0)` ,  `With Me.Range("A7").CurrentRegion` and it works perfectly (No other changes).

When I put it into my working workbook which is a table from a power query, it filters based on selection, but for some reason when I select "All" it does not Unfilter the Column?

Comment: Could it be perhaps something to do with my actual worksheet has 23 columns and to do with `With Me.Range("A7").CurrentRegion` ?

Comment: I've test the code on a PQ table w/o any issue. I would suggest you post a new question. 
[What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)

Comment: Hi @taller, have tried iterations I could think of, still can't get to Unfilter on selecting "All". As you said, I have now posted my Follow Up Question. Thank you.

Comment: I've answered your new questoin.