# VBA Code for Multi Drop Down Auto-Filters in Worksheet Follow Up New Question

Tags: excel, vba

with reference to my prior Question that @taller kindly helped me with solution for, please may someone assist me with this follow-up issue/question.

[Prior Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78050565/vba-code-for-multi-drop-down-auto-filters-in-worksheet)

Thank you @taller for your help to date.

As per the initial question, I successfully managed to get this example code working with Drop Down List selections, that after Selecting a Filter and Filters the relevant Column, then on changing the Selection back to "All" it Unfilters the relevant Column.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const HEADER = 8
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C2:C6")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim vCol, vCrit
        vCol = Application.Match(Target.Offset(0, -1), Me.Rows(HEADER), 0)
        If VBA.IsError(vCol) Then Exit Sub
        With Me.Range("A8").CurrentRegion
            If Target.Value = "All" Then
                If Me.AutoFilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol
                End If
            Else
                vCrit = Target.Text
                If IsDate(vCrit) Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=CLng(CDate(vCol)), Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlAnd
                Else
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Prior Solution]

This works perfectly and when I change back to "All" it Unfilters the prior dropdown list selection.

I have then tried the same Code in my Work Production environment, modifying for different Header Row (Row 7) and Selection Range as follows

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const HEADER = 7
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B5")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim vCol, vCrit
        vCol = Application.Match(Target.Offset(0, -1), Me.Rows(HEADER), 0)
        If VBA.IsError(vCol) Then Exit Sub
        With Me.Range("A7").CurrentRegion
            If Target.Value = "All" Then
                If Me.AutoFilterMode Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol
                End If
            Else
                vCrit = Target.Text
                If IsDate(vCrit) Then
                    .AutoFilter Field:=CLng(CDate(vCol)), Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlAnd
                Else
                    .AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

With the following Power Query Table which has significantly more Columns (23).
[image: Work Table]

For some reason I am unable to get the Selected Filter to Unfilter on changing selection back to "All" in my Work Workbook, unlike my Example Test worked. The Selection Filter works, but not the Unfilter on selecting the "All" again.

I have tried various iterations, commenting out some lines re Date which is not relevant in my Work Workbook to no avail. I have checked the Formatting of the Text, both in the Dropdown List and the Selection Box as well.

I am fresh out of trying to fix which I have done over the course of the week.

I am pretty sure it is something simple I am overlooking and not seeing.

Many thanks

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- PQ table is a ListObject. The code of autofitler is little bit different.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const HEADER = 7
    If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2:B5")) Is Nothing Then
        Dim vCol, vCrit
        vCol = Application.Match(Target.Offset(, -1), Me.Rows(HEADER), 0)
        If VBA.IsError(vCol) Then Exit Sub
        With Me.Range("A" & HEADER).ListObject
            If Target.Value = "All" Then
                If .AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
                    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=vCol
                End If
            Else
                vCrit = Target.Text
                If IsDate(vCrit) Then
                    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=CLng(CDate(vCol)), Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlAnd
                Else
                    .Range.AutoFilter Field:=vCol, Criteria1:=vCrit, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @taller, absolute star, works a dream. Whilst I knew a PQ Table was a ListObject, for the life of me I didn't know or realise that that would make a difference.
Thank you, appreciated for your help.